# How to call webservice(API) in background and also refresh stored local DB data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am make app related to display listing but my app too much stuck.
For example,
when i am click on purchase data tab list call API and display data from API. Again tap same tab then again call API and data display from API that's why my app take too much load.

For solution i stored 10 records in sqlite database and in background call API but again stuck view.

```
GetPurchaseDataHistoryFromlocalDB()//Get data from local DB(sqlite)
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async(execute: { () -> Void in
            self.GetPurchasedata(offset: self.offset, limit: self.limit)//API called
        })
```

so any one have solution for Load API in background and also refresh local DB data then please help me.

Thank you.

Comment: what does your `GetPurchaseDataHistoryFromlocalDB` and `GetPurchasedata` method do?

Comment: Hello Pratik,
GetPurchasedata is method for get Data from API.
GetPurchaseDataHistoryFromlocalDB is method for get Data from local database.(sqlite)

Comment: are you using alamofire for making api call?

Comment: Hello Pratik,
yes i am using alamofire for calling API.

Comment: Hello Pratik, please help me it's urgent.i tried to enable alamofire cache but it's not working.Not data fetch from cache. :(